# My Oracle reports run fine until I try to add a graph to the layout?

Tags: oracle, report

OS: Windows 7 32 bit.
Oracle Reports 10g 10.1.2.0.2
I get the following errors when opening the Graphing Wizard... In the first message box I get the following:

REP-0069: Internal Error
REP-0: java.lang.NullPointerException

Clicking OK, results in this message:
REP-6212: Unable to parse graph definition

Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had been struggling with the same issue for a couple of days until I found out that it is a compatibility problem.

What you should do is set the compatibility mode to Windows XP, if that doesn't work try with Windows98/Windows Me then.

Right click on your Oracle Reports icon > properties > compatibility > check "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and select as I mentioned above Windows Xp or Windows 98/Windows Me.

It worked for me on windows 8 64bits and Oracle Reports 10g 10.1.2.3.0.